# how to connect arduino and usb camera with xiaomi nano router (openwrt)?

Tags: arduino, webcam, router, openwrt, serial-communication

I want to develop a similar project based on [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/RC-Intelligent-Car-Robot-based-on-Smart-Arduino/) project, but i want to use [xiaomi nano router](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Xiaomi-Mi-WiFi-Nano-Smart-Router-Youth-Edition-802-11n-300Mbps-Wireless-Router-/281976666732?var=&hash=item41a71e7a6c:m:mgsdpU4dwlGewhwAJUidzqg) instead of TP-WR703n router.

[image]
The problem is that my router does not have an USB port to communicate with other devices (arduino mega and camera). 
My solution is:

- Using a [CP2102 converter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/CP2102-USB-2-0-to-UART-TTL-6PIN-Module-Serial-Converter-Free-Cables-/130683943875) and a [female to female USB converter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Standard-USB2-0-Type-A-Female-to-Female-Extension-Converter-Connector-Adapter-/371309283369?hash=item5673c20829:g:dqQAAOSwqu9VNIiO) to make USB port for my router.
- Using USB hub to connect with arduino and camera.

Is my solution possible?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not how USB works.

Comment: could you please explain to me the reason?

Comment: USB to TTL serial converter won't make a device magically a USB host device. And matching connectors doesn't mean matching protocols.

Comment: Why not use a Raspberry pi instead of a router?

Comment: Because i want to create a motor car with batter supply and i think using battery for Raspberry is not a good idea since it require a stable power supply. But i will consider your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't make a USB port out of UART port. The CP2101 converter works the other way around - it makes a serial port out of your USB port.

Comment: So, is there any converter that can transfer data in both directions ?

Comment: It does transfer data in both directions, and you can use it to communicate with Arduino board, for example, but not with the webcam (which expects USB line, not serial console). However, the UART port of the router is already occupied by the operating system (it uses it as debug console), so it won't be very convenient to use it for stable communication.